# Question about a rotated triangle and distance of points

Tags: geometry

Let be $abc$ a triangle

Rotate the triangle 180° around the midpoint of $bc$. The point where $a$ used to be is now called $d$ and the midpoints of $bd$ is $e'$ and the midpoint of $ac$ is b'.
I want to show, that $ad$ is divided through $bb'$ and $e'c$ in three equal parts.

I am starring at my picture for quite some time now without an idea how to prove that..[image]

Any ideas very appreciated

Comment: Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or contest, give the intended audience and perhaps say something about the tools and/or techniques that might typically be used. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it keeps others from explaining things you already understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dashed lines meet at triangle centroids, and triangle centroids divide their medians in a 2:1 ratio. The desired conclusion follows from the fact that $abc$ and $dcb$ are congruent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $d^\prime, a^\prime$ be the intersections of $ad$ with respectively $ ce^\prime$ and $bb^\prime$. As the angle of the rotation is equal to $\pi$, $bb^\prime$ is parallel to $ce^\prime$.

Then using Thales theorem twice, you get that the length of $d^\prime a^\prime$ is equal to the one of $dd^\prime$ and to the one of $aa^\prime$ as desired.